# How to concatenate my text with value fetch from model?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to print "Ticket has been generated for DL verification: value of InstaveritasType" in one line. I am able to get the value from the model but I am not able to print it in single line.

Here is my code:

```
  <h1><font color="#fa1801" face="Algerian" size="5"><strong>Ticket has 
   been generated for DL verification : <p 
   th:text="${InstaveritasType}"></p></strong> </font></h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ticket has been generated for DL verification : `<span th:inline="text">[[${InstaveritasType}]]</span>`

Or use `<span>` tag instead of `<p>` !

```
<h1><font color="#fa1801" face="Algerian" size="5"><strong>Ticket has 
   been generated for DL verification : <span 
   th:text="${InstaveritasType}"></span></strong> </font></h1>
```

Comment: it will not work !! it will print like : icket has been generated for DL verification : ${InstaveritasType} not with the value of InstaveritasType.

Comment: Try with `span`